# Upgraded to 12.04 always freezing

Tags: 12.04

I never had a problem with UBUNTU 10.04 till I upgraded to 12.04, now I am freezing all the time, having problem rebooting, it's a nightmare. Does anyone know what is happening and what I can do? I am no real Ubuntu literate.

Comment: What are your specs? try using [old gnome instead of unity](http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/classicgnome)?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe its because of graphic issue. Ubuntu 12.04 use different desktop environment wich can effect resourses of your hardware.As ubuntu 10.04 lts user you can install gnome fallback desktop and see similar gnome 2 environment in latest lts version wich i guess yuo prefer as it more stable ..or just install other desktop environment Or else try to disable some fancy compiz effects and use 2d unity mode( chose it while login in )